# Can we recover old MathOverflow Meta "Tea" discussions?

Tags: support, tea

Today I flagged a question as needing to be made community wiki. I thought about why, and found [this old question of mine](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3573/why-was-this-question-made-community-wiki) here. Carlo Beenakker helpfully linked to a thread on the old tea. [Link reproduced here](http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/247/question-mysteriously-becoming-community-wiki/?Focus=4242). But that tqft place is down, as well as the tea place that redirects to it, as Martin [pointed out here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4438/tea-archive-mathoverflow-tqft-net-seems-to-be-down). I could not find a copy of the relevant discussion Carlo linked to anywhere online, including the Wayback machine.

> Can someone find these old threads and make them available again?

Comment: Just as a reminder I will add that https://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/247/question-mysteriously-becoming-community-wiki/ will redirect to tqft - which does not work now. The particular thread that you mention [can be found in Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20151031151418/https://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/247/question-mysteriously-becoming-community-wiki/). And - as mentioned in the post you linked - I made at least temporary backup [on my website](https://msleziak.com/mathoverflow/tea/discussion/247/question-mysteriously-becoming-community-wiki/).

Comment: In case it is useful, the creation of the redirect was announced here: [tea.mathoverflow.net deprecated](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3960).

Comment: When I searched in the Wayback machine, I put the link I got from Carlo: http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/247/question-mysteriously-becoming-community-wiki/?Focus=4242. I then had the idea to change it to https://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/247/, and got nothing. But the link Martin gave is https://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/247/question-mysteriously-becoming-community-wiki/. The lesson is that the Wayback machine cares about what comes after the number in the URL (even if your web browser doesn't, and redirects)

Comment: In case some of them are useful somebody, here is a  link to [a few comments in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19138/conversation/looking-for-tea-in-the-wayback-machine).