# Should this question have been CW?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

Yesterday I asked a big-list question ([Examples of errors in computational combinatorics results](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/438267/examples-of-errors-in-computational-combinatorics-results)). The question is naturally big-list because it asks for various examples. Now I am **not** quite familiar with the community understanding of what is CW, but the big-list tag help says "Such a question should **typically** be in Community Wiki mode (CW)" [emphasis mine].

However, one answerer was (IMHO quite understandably) surprised and somewhat disappointed that their answer is also automatically CW. I feel a bit bad for this answerer, who provided a very well-thought answer, which must have taken nontrivial effort. Yet no reputation benefit because CW. I could, of course, grant them a small bounty to remedy the situation.

But this begs the question: should the question have been CW after all? I understand that at least one rationale for big-list questions being CW is "[to allow] the voting system to be used more effectively to rank the list without damaging the reputation of users who give bad responses." (from a [comment](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3573/why-was-this-question-made-community-wiki#comment15796_3573) by Carlo Beenakker to a 2018 Meta question). Is this the key issue and does it apply here, or are there other reasons for big-list being CW?

Comment: The general tradition on MO is that big-list questions, or in general questions which do not have a single correct answer, should *usually* be CW. Also, questions which are rather soft questions than precise mathematical questions should *usually* be CW. These cannot be exact "hard" rules, of course.

Comment: I guess the tag ([meta-tag:specific-question]) might be suitable here - at least if this is meant mainly to be about this particular question. (Not if you want to have a general discussion - and this question is used just as an example. See also [the tag-info for this tag](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/specific-question/info).)